# Can I connect the pull-up resistors of I2C lines to 3.3 V on a 1.8 V device?

Tags: i2c, logic-level, open-drain

I need to use the following sensor in my project : **AS7341 (ams)**. It is a spectrometer whose data are accessed through an I2C inteface. The datasheet can be found [here](https://www.mouser.fr/datasheet/2/588/AMS_03152019_AS7341_DS000504_1_00-1891973.pdf).

It is stated that its power supply should be 1.8 V, and regarding the INT pin : *"Connect pull up resistor to 1.8V"*.

I need to communicate with this sensor from an MCU whose supply is 3.3 V.

I have taken a look at the [user manual](https://www.mouser.fr/datasheet/2/588/AS7341_UG000400_5_00-1956070.pdf) of the **AS7341 EVAL KIT (asm)**, which is the evaluation kit of the **AS7341**.

On the schematics (page 12), they connect SDA, SCL and INT pin to 3.3 V through a pull-up resistor.

I would have naturally connected them to 1.8 V and used logic level translators to communicate with the sensor. But if it works with 3.3 V I'm more than interested.

So my questions are : Will it work? Is it always possible to do this with open-drain outputs? Why don't they comply with the datasheet regarding the INT pin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will work.

No, it is not always possible to do so on I2C pins (as they are not only open-drain outputs, they are also inputs). It depends on the specification of the specific device.

They do comply with the datasheet, as the datasheet states that the SCL, SDA and INT pin have maximum input voltage of 3.6 V, i.e. they are 3.3 V tolerant.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the "absolute maximum ratings" (figure 5, page 7), you get a never exceed voltage of 3.6V for SDA, SCL and INT.

So it is garanteed that a 3.3V voltage will not imeditly destroy the AS7341. I havn't found however any clear proof that this is allowed for continuous operation (the absolute maximum ratings do not garantee correct operation, nor a decent life time, just that if it happens occasionnaly you will not destroy your device).

What's more, as I2C is pulled up through a resistor >1k, the current is quite high, so if there are internal protection diodes, they should be able to handle the current.

If it is just for some testing, I would say it's worse trying (and if in the eval board they use it, then it is probably quite reliable). If you need high reliability (for example if you plan to do mass production), then maybe it's best to double-check with the manufacturer to check if reliability is affected.

You might also look about the range of "high" values for your MCU : if you are lucky, it goes down bellow 1.8V, and you can just pull up to 1.8V and still use it (or you may cheat and pull to something like 2.5V).

But generally speaking, no, you cannot assume that you are allowed to pull an I2C bus higher than the normal I/O level (some ICs accept it, other not). What can alwys be done, is to pull up to the lowest voltage (in your case 1.8V) : if the other end still sees it as a "high" level, then you are fine

Comment: Thank you, you are right I will ask the manufacturer to be sure.

Comment: if there were internal protection diodes on those pins to VCC, then I2C wouldnt work, since those didoes would pull down the I2C bus. The fact that they use it in the eval board suggests those pins dont have this issue, so it should be fine to use. If you really wanted to be sure, you could ask AMS